# Properties of King's Dream fractal

Tags: general-topology, fractals

My question is focused on the King's Dream fractal, which can be defined as follows (nice pictures can be found [here](http://softology.com.au/tutorials/attractors2d/tutorial.htm)) :
$$ \Omega = \{f^n(0.1,0.1) \;\vert\; n \in \mathbb N \} \quad
    f(x,y)=(\sin(ax)+b\sin(ay),\sin(cx)+d \sin(cy))$$
where $-3 < a,c < 3$ and $-0.5<b,d<1.5$ are given.

> Then, I was wondering if $K=\overline \Omega$ is symmetric w.r.t. $(0,0)$, i.e. $(x,y) \in K \implies (-x,-y)\in K$ (at least for some values of $a,b,c$ and $d$, e.g. those given below).
>
> I don't think that $\Omega$ itself is symmetric w.r.t $(0,0)$. Looking at the picture below, it seems that it could be the case for $K$, but it doesn't appear obvious when looking at the definition of $f$.

I was also wondering whether $K$ is connected. If these properties hold, I don't know how this could be proved...

Here is a picture of $\{f^n(0.1,0.1) \;\vert\; 0 \leq n \leq N = 9000 \}$ for $$a=2.879879,b=−0.765145,c=−0.966918,d=0.744728.$$
[image: King's dream fractal for N = 9000, a=2.879879,b=−0.765145,c=−0.966918,d=0.744728]

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: it may depend on the parameters, obviously the case $a=b=c=d=0$ results in $\Omega=\{(0.1,0.1),(0,0)\}$ which is not connected (and uninteresting). I suspect that if $a,b,c,d$ each is close to $0$, then $f^n(0.1,0.1)\to0$ so $K$ would be a converging sequence of points and won't be connected. If $b=d=0$ but $a=c>0$ is small, then all iterations are positive, small, and converge monotonically to $0$, so they remain in the first quadrant and cannot be symmetric with respect to the origin. (Use that $0<\sin(x)<x$ for $x>0$.)This is not an answer but you might want to clarify the interesting cases

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was indeed interested in non trivial cases such as $a=2.879879, b=-0.765145,c=-0.966918,d=0.744728$ which seems to be symmetric w.r.t. the origin.

Comment: I bet if you plot a 2-dimensional map over two of the four variables (fix the other two), and plotted a pixel black if the attractor is connected, the resulting plot could also contain fractal properties.

Comment: @Mark Jeronimus : so there is "no hope" (i.e. it may be very difficult) to prove that $\overline{\Omega}$ is symmetric w.r.t to the origin (for the values I gave above for instance) ?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506900

Comment: (Possibly related: Douady and Hubbard have shown that the Mandelbrot set is connected, and T. Bousch in 1988 showed that the closure of the set of zeros of Littlewood polynomials is connected.)

Comment: Pictures can be found in Matousek's book on discrete maths.