# Symmetry of King's dream fractal (orbit of a 2-dimensional iterated function system is a parallelogram?)

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, fractals, iterated-function-system

For fixed real numbers $a,b,c,d$ define the map $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$f : (x, y) \longmapsto (\phi(ax) + b \cdot \phi(ay),\hspace{1em} 
                          \phi(cx) + d \cdot \phi(cy)),
\qquad \phi(z) := \sin(z).$$

Given a point $(x_0, y_0) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ we consider its orbits under the iterates of $f$, i.e.,
$$\Omega := \{f^n(x_0, y_0) \;\vert\; n \in \mathbb Z_{>0} \}$$

Here is a question I asked myself after plotting some of these sets $\Omega$:

> Is it true that for $x_0 = y_0 = 1$ and $(a, b, c, d) = (3, -1, 3, -3)$, the closure $\overline{\Omega} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is equal to the parallelogram $P$ with vertices $\pm (0, 2), \pm (2, 4)$ ?

---

Thoughts:

- This is confirmed experimentally (using SAGE, see the code below), using $n \leq 500000$ points:
  [image: kings_dream_fractal_A3Bm1C3Dm3_x0y1_N500000 parallelogram]
- Since the sine function takes values in $[-1, 1]$, it is clear that $\Omega$ is contained in the parallelogram $P$ (hence $\overline{\Omega} \subset P$) : indeed we have
  $$f(x, y) 
  = (\sin(3x) - \sin(3y), \sin(3x) - 3 \sin(3y)) 
  = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \sin(3x) \\ \sin(3y) \end{pmatrix}$$
  and the image of the square $[-1, 1]^2$ under the linear map $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -3 \end{pmatrix}$ is $P$.
- The appearance of a parallelogram is probably explained by the fact that $a = c$. In general, we obtained "fractal" objects like in this question asked some years ago by the same author: [Properties of King's Dream fractal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577411/properties-of-kings-dream-fractal)
- When we replace $\sin(x)$ by $\phi(x) = \{ 1.5 x \}$ (where $\{ … \}$ denotes the fractional part), we also get a parallelogram for $(a, b, c, d) = (3, -1, 3, -3)$ but NOT for $(a, b, c, d) = (1, -1, 1, -2)$.